# Compilation fails with "error: ‘next_ioctl’ undeclared (first use in this function)" despite I included dlfcn.h

Tags: c, compiler-errors, ld, word-wrap

Trying to compile an example of wrapping library from [here](http://scaryreasoner.wordpress.com/2007/11/17/using-ld_preload-libraries-and-glibc-backtrace-function-for-debugging/)

I had to include `stdio.h` and `stdlib.h`, and came to that code:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#define _USE_GNU

#include <signal.h>
#include <execinfo.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

static void show_stackframe() {
  void *trace[16];
  char **messages = (char **)NULL;
  int i, trace_size = 0;

  trace_size = backtrace(trace, 16);
  messages = backtrace_symbols(trace, trace_size);
  printf("[bt] Execution path:\n");
  for (i=0; i < trace_size; ++i)
        printf("[bt] %s\n", messages[i]);
}

int ioctl(int fd, int request, void *data)
{
        char *msg;

        if (next_ioctl == NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr, "ioctl : wrapping ioctl\n");
                fflush(stderr);
                // next_ioctl = dlsym((void *) -11, /* RTLD_NEXT, */ "ioctl");
                next_ioctl = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "ioctl");
                fprintf(stderr, "next_ioctl = %p\n", next_ioctl);
                fflush(stderr);
                if ((msg = dlerror()) != NULL) {
                        fprintf(stderr, "ioctl: dlopen failed : %s\n", msg);
                        fflush(stderr);
                        exit(1);
                } else
                        fprintf(stderr, "ioctl: wrapping done\n");
                fflush(stderr);
        }
        if (request == 1) { /* SCSI_IOCTL_SEND_COMMAND ? */
                /* call back trace */
                fprintf(stderr, "SCSI_IOCTL_SEND_COMMAND ioctl\n");
                fflush(stderr);
                show_stackframe();
        }
        return next_ioctl(fd, request, data);
}
```

and Makefile

```
#
# Makefile
#

all:    libs test_ioctl

libs:   libwrap_ioctl.so

libwrap_ioctl.so:   wrap_ioctl.c
    rm -f libwrap_ioctl.so*
    gcc -fPIC -shared -Wl,-soname,libwrap_ioctl.so.1 -ldl -o libwrap_ioctl.so.1.0  wrap_ioctl.c
    ln -s libwrap_ioctl.so.1.0 libwrap_ioctl.so.1
    ln -s libwrap_ioctl.so.1 libwrap_ioctl.so

clean: 
    rm -f libwrap_ioctl.so* test_ioctl
```

and stuck in these errors, despite dlfcn.h is included.

```
~/my_src/native/glibc_wrapper > make
rm -f libwrap_ioctl.so*
gcc -fPIC -shared -Wl,-soname,libwrap_ioctl.so.1 -ldl -o libwrap_ioctl.so.1.0  wrap_ioctl.c
wrap_ioctl.c: In function ‘ioctl’:
wrap_ioctl.c:26: error: ‘next_ioctl’ undeclared (first use in this function)
wrap_ioctl.c:26: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
wrap_ioctl.c:26: error: for each function it appears in.)
make: *** [libwrap_ioctl.so] Ошибка 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dlfcn.h` itself doesn't define any symbol with name `next_`smth. (In SUS, dlfcn.h only defines several `dl*` functions and `RTLD_` macro: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/dlfcn.h.html)

You should define this as pointer to function in your program code in explicit way. Something like this: (taken from https://port70.net/svn/misc/remac/remac.c or from https://github.com/itm/forward-sensor/blob/master/preload.c or ... any google search for `"next_ioctl"`):

```
static int (*next_ioctl) (int fd, int request, void *data) = NULL;
```

Or, if you want a collective blog-reading session, there is additional line in the blog post with ioctl overloading: http://scaryreasoner.wordpress.com/2007/11/17/using-ld_preload-libraries-and-glibc-backtrace-function-for-debugging/  (just before first huge code fragment)

> Then, declare a function pointer to hold the value
>   of the “real” ioctl() function from glibc:

```
static int (*next_ioctl)(int fd, int request, void *data) = NULL;
```

> Then declare your replacement ioctl function:

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation, osgx!

I didn't find the source of *test_ioctl.c* Can you provide an example code to test the compiled wrapper?

Comment: What? I have no any "test_ioctl.c".

Comment: Ok, I just asked for few lines to test the wrapper.

Comment: zuba, you can do a random ioctl call just to get a error: open any file, and do `ioctl(file_desc, 1234567, NULL);`. If you want real ioctl, you should find some device (file in `/dev/`) which is writable by you and capable of working with ioctl. I think, audio device can be used, there are ioctls to change volume and audio settings.

Comment: Thank you, osgx! Good luck to you !!

Comment: I'm noob in C and I need `a lot` of practice indeed

Answer (score 1):

You missed to declare `next_ioctl`.

Just add

<strike>void * next_ioctl = NULL;</strike>

```
int (*next_ioctl) (int, int, ...) = NULL;
```

to `main()`.

Comment: This ("Just add...") will fail at `return next_ioctl(fd, request, data);`

Comment: @osgx: You are right, I missed to scroll down the code snippet to its end.

Comment: And Zuba missed some code in the [blog post](http://scaryreasoner.wordpress.com/2007/11/17/using-ld_preload-libraries-and-glibc-backtrace-function-for-debugging/)